# Swagger change UI parameters using Fastendpoints

Tags: c#, oauth, swagger, fusionauth, fast-endpoints

I'm using FastEndpoints with .NET 8 and implementing an OAuth flow using FusionAuth. The integration is working fine, but I'm facing an issue with the Swagger UI when using the `AuthorizationCode` flow.

My issue is related to the Swagger UI's `oauth2RedirectUrl` parameter.

Here's a snippet of my Program.cs where I set up Swagger and configure its UI:

```cs
bld.Services.AddFastEndpoints().AddAuthorization().SwaggerDocument(options =>
{
    //Code...
    // Security scheme used on swagger:
    var securityScheme = new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = NSwag.OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new NSwag.OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new NSwag.OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = authorizationUrl,
                TokenUrl = tokenUrl,
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "offline_access", "Offline access" },
                    }
            }
        },
    };

    options.DocumentSettings = s =>
    {
        //Code...
        //Set security Scheme:
        s.AddAuth("oauth2", securityScheme);
    };
});


app.UseFastEndpoints(o =>
{
  // Code...
}).UseSwaggerGen(o => { }, uiConfig =>
{
    uiConfig.ServerUrl = fusionAuthConfig["RedirectUri"];
    uiConfig.OAuth2Client = new OAuth2ClientSettings
    {
        Realm = "",
        ClientId = fusionAuthConfig["ApplicationId"],
        ClientSecret = fusionAuthConfig["ClientSecret"],
        AppName = fusionAuthConfig["ApplicationId"],
        ScopeSeparator = ",",
        AdditionalQueryStringParameters =
                {
                    { "tenantId", fusionAuthConfig["TenantId"] },
                    { "code_challenge", "XXXXXX" },
                    { "code_challenge_method", "S256" },
                }
    };
});
```

Swagger UI to generate the UI ( `SwaggerUiSettings : SwaggerUiSettingsBase`) they have:

```
    internal override async Task<string> TransformHtmlAsync(string html, HttpRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder(html);
        OAuth2ClientSettings oAuth2ClientSettings = OAuth2Client ?? new OAuth2ClientSettings();
        foreach (PropertyInfo runtimeProperty in oAuth2ClientSettings.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            object value = runtimeProperty.GetValue(oAuth2ClientSettings);
            if (value is ICollection value2)
            {
                htmlBuilder.Replace("{" + runtimeProperty.Name + "}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value2));
            }
            else if (value is bool flag)
            {
                htmlBuilder.Replace("{" + runtimeProperty.Name + "}", flag.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
            }
            else
            {
                htmlBuilder.Replace("{" + runtimeProperty.Name + "}", value?.ToString() ?? "");
            }
        }

        ICollection<SwaggerUi3Route> collection = ((SwaggerRoutesFactory == null) ? SwaggerRoutes : (await SwaggerRoutesFactory(request, cancellationToken)).ToList());
        ICollection<SwaggerUi3Route> source = collection;
        htmlBuilder.Replace("{Urls}", (!source.Any()) ? "undefined" : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source.Select((SwaggerUi3Route r) => new SwaggerUi3Route(r.Name, base.TransformToExternalPath(r.Url.Substring(base.MiddlewareBasePath?.Length ?? 0), request)))));
        htmlBuilder.Replace("{ValidatorUrl}", ValidateSpecification ? "undefined" : "null").Replace("{AdditionalSettings}", GenerateAdditionalSettings(AdditionalSettings)).Replace("{EnableTryItOut}", EnableTryItOut.ToString().ToLower())
            .Replace("{RedirectUrl}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerUrl) ? ("window.location.origin + \"" + base.TransformToExternalPath(base.Path, request) + "/oauth2-redirect.html\"") : ("\"" + ServerUrl + base.TransformToExternalPath(base.Path, request) + "/oauth2-redirect.html\""))
            .Replace("{CustomStyle}", GetCustomStyleHtml(request))
            .Replace("{CustomScript}", GetCustomScriptHtml(request))
            .Replace("{CustomHeadContent}", CustomHeadContent)
            .Replace("{DocumentTitle}", DocumentTitle);
        return htmlBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

They make this:

```cs
.Replace("{RedirectUrl}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerUrl) ? ("window.location.origin + \"" + base.TransformToExternalPath(base.Path, request) + "/oauth2-redirect.html\"") : ("\"" + ServerUrl + base.TransformToExternalPath(base.Path, request) + "/oauth2-redirect.html\""))
```

Setting redirect_url to `"/oauth2-redirect.html\"`.

I have tried to set by my own the redirect URI sending a parameter but I was not able to figure out the way. I have already tried sending it as `AdditionalQueryStringParameters = { "redirect_uri", fusionAuthConfig["RedirectUri"] }`
but I get 2 redirect uri's parameter. I know that in Swagger it exists a parameter called `oauth2RedirectUrl` (https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) but I'm not able to change it.

Does anybody knows how can I change that parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out [FE staff community on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/933662816458645504/1197223459856601178) we made a fast work around.

Just set the parameter with: `uiConfig.AdditionalSettings["oauth2RedirectUrl"] = fusionAuthConfig["RedirectUriSwagger"];`

So we have:

```cs
.UseSwaggerGen(o => { }, uiConfig =>
{
    uiConfig.AdditionalSettings["oauth2RedirectUrl"] = fusionAuthConfig["RedirectUriSwagger"];
    uiConfig.ServerUrl = fusionAuthConfig["RedirectUri"];
    uiConfig.OAuth2Client = new OAuth2ClientSettings
    {
        ClientId = fusionAuthConfig["ApplicationId"],
        ClientSecret = fusionAuthConfig["ClientSecret"],
        AppName = fusionAuthConfig["ApplicationId"],
        ScopeSeparator = ",",
        AdditionalQueryStringParameters =
                {
                    { "tenantId", fusionAuthConfig["TenantId"] },
                    { "code_challenge", "CCCCCCC" },
                    { "code_challenge_method", "S256" },
                }
    };
});
```